# Spring Data Couchbase / Spring Boot: could not get nested list of an object

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase

I am new to couchbase and I am encountering an issue on fetching document from couchbase. The nested list of object (List of Devices) is always null.  I used Spring Boot and Spring Data Couchbase.

Model (User.java)

```
@Document
public class User implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private String id;

   @Field
   @NotNull
   private String username;

   @Field
   @NotNull
   private String password;

   @Field
   private List<Devices> deviceList;

   /** getter and setter here **/
}
```

Model (Devices.java)

```
@Document
public class Devices implements Serializable {
   @Field
   @NotNull
   private String deviceId;

   @Field
   @NotNull
   private String status;

   @Field
   @NotNull
   private String createdDate;

   @Reference
   private User user;

   /** getter and setter here **/
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
public interface UserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<User, String>{

   User findOneByUsername(String username);

   User findOneByDeviceId(String deviceId);
}
```

Document

```
{
   "username": "username",
   "password": "password",
   "devicesList": [
    {
      "deviceId": "abc123",
      "status": "deactived",
      "createdDate": "2017-07-28 15:59:13"
    },
    {
      "deviceId": "abc456",
      "status": "actived",
      "createdDate": "2017-07-28 15:59:13"
    },
    {
      "deviceId": "abc789",
      "status": "deactived",
      "createdDate": "2017-07-28 15:59:13"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result

```
{
   "responseCode": 200,
   "data": {
      "id": "user-login-03",
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password",
      "deviceList": null
   }
}
```

I hope you could help me regarding this matter. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class, attribute name is **deviceList** but in json it is **devicesList**.
The persisted json can not be converted to POJO since the attribute names are different.